# Why is 'jQuery-Rails' often outside of the asset group

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, gemfile

Why is it that I often see `gem 'jquery-rails` outside of the `:assets` group?

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', " ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', " ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Will there be buggy behavior if I put it inside?

Thanks!

Comment: HIya, you can figure this out read here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html ; why the asset group is there. Hope this helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `jquery-rails` gem provides some test helpers also. So perhaps for that reason people prefer to put it outside the `:assets` group.

However, the `:assets` group is included in development and testing environment, so you should be perfectly safe to place `jquery-rails` in your `:assets` group if you like.

Just make sure you precompile your assets before you deploy your application.

Comment: - 1 . If you have ever used `jquery-rails` in `:assets` group you would know that it is `NOT` perfectly safe to put into `:assets` group. From time to time, jquery-rails can break down, and no precompiling will help. Putting it outside the `:assets` would do the work.

Comment: @Aleks as long as you precompile you assets in the right environment you should be fine. Precompiling in the production environment, as mentioned, would not work.

Comment: @Aleks Note that I say that the assets group is included in development and testing, I do **not** say that it is included in production. I also said to precompile assets **before** deployment.

Answer (score 4):

The real answer for this is that `gem 'jquery-rails'` can often break up on the production, and there would be no standard way of fixing this other then initializing the gem itself from the beginning. I have seen this problems on heroku.

The fix for that is to put `jquery-rails` outside `:assets` group, and that way you would be sure that it will not break up.

Even the question is an old one, I wanted to make sure that that is the reason, and you would probably need to put `'jquery-rails'` **OUTSIDE** `:assets` group.