# "Gemfile syntax error" after editing Gemfile, running bundle install or bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am a Rails newbie and trying to follow http://railstutorial.org guide. 
I am using:

- gem 2.0.3
- bundler 1.3.5
- rails 3.2.13
- ruby 2.0.0-p195

When I perform `bundle update` or `bundle install` after editing the Gemfile, I get the following errors:

```
roberts-imac-6:first_app bobbaird001$ bundle update
**Gemfile syntax error:**
roberts-imac-6:first_app bobbaird001$ bundle install
**Gemfile syntax error:**
```

Here is the Gemfile (I have removed the rows that are commented out)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'cdacd
  end
  gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

remove the `end` below `sqlite` and `jquery-rails`, remove cdacd at the end of `uglifier`, and correct the indentation like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
```

only the gems inside the `do` blocks need indentation.

hope this helps clarify things.

Comment: I think jquery-rails is meant to be inside the assets group. **Update:** or maybe not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730386/why-is-jquery-rails-often-outside-of-the-asset-group

Comment: It would seem logical. But the generated `Gemfile` has it outside the assets group. Regardless, the `:assets` group is being removed from Rails 4.

Answer (score 2):

you have syntax error
replace this

```
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'cdacd
```

to this

```
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the extra characters mentioned by @Ruba Ruba, based on the Gemfile in your question you have a few extra end statements - you really only need the one on the line after uglifier.